# Problem opening MVC project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I was given an MVC project, but I can't open it. Visual Studio says 'project type is not supported'.
I have Visual Studio 2008 (maybe professional) + mvc last version (2 beta).
What must I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is an ASP.NET MVC V1 project, so you might need to install [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en) as well.

Comment: how it is possible? on ms site only last version of mvc

Comment: The project type GUID isn't the same for v1 and v2.  You need v1 installed to open v1 projects.